# Timeout was reached for custom command in slack

Tags: php, slack

I have a custom slack command that calls a php script. My script is just a hello world-like script:

```
<?php
echo "testing";
?>
```

I have copied and pasted the exact url that is in the command's integration settings into my browser and it works. However, when I run the custom command from slack, I get the following error:

```
Darn – that slash command didn't work (error message: `Timeout was reached`).
Manage the command at (link)
```

Any idea what might be going on here?

Answer (score 0):

Self answer:

I was using my server's local ip and my slack server was not able to see that, obviously.